# How to find difference between two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays like this.

```
Array
(
[14] => 1
[15] => 1
[13] => 2
)

Array
(
[14] => 1
[15] => 1
[13] => 2
)
```

Here array key and value are same. If array key or value is different, I have to return error value.
Like the second array is

```
Array
(
[12] => 1
[15] => 3
[13] => 2
)
```

2 arrays should be unique. If key or value not unique, it should return error.

```
$k=array_intersect($CARTS,$store_cart);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `array_diff` the function returns you all entries from the first array which are not the same.

So you can check with count the return if its bigger then 0 for example. Then you know, that the array is not the same.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php